# Does receiver class have to be declared as public?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm using android studio and it complains if the receiver class is not defined as public in the manifest.
I wasn't able to find a document that says this, so is there a such?

Answer (score 1):

Every component registered in the manifest needs to be `public` and have a zero argument `public` constructor. Otherwise, Android cannot create instances of the component. I doubt that this requirement is formally documented, though.

Answer (score 0):

YUP you have to define receiver class as public, its necessary